# Identify what resources communicate in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm looking for a method to identify what resources communicate with each other.
For example: What function is activated by what web-app and then what database that function accesses to get the data. Thanks!

It would be the best to have this data available via API but that's just a plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that springs to mind is using the [Application Map in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net), it will show the dependencies.

[image]

But, in order for this to work Application Insights needs to be enabled in your applications/services.

The map is generated based on data residing in Application Insights. That data can be accessed using the [rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) but you will have to craft the queries to get this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using distributed tracing (currently in preview for Azure Functions). Another option is adding Azure Application Insights and checking the Application Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Application Insights to get the view of all the connected services. It's also provides you the following benefits.

1. What is the response time for each of the dependency. It also provide us to drill through the traces.
2. It also provides the number of error that are occurring in each of those dependencies and allows us to drill through individual traces.

If you haven't integrated Application Insights yet to you app, you can follow through the article [here](https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2020/07/11/6-steps-to-integrate-application-insights-with-net-core-application-hosted-in-azure-app-service/).